# Delay on recieving message on (select) chat-client

Tags: c, select, client, chat

I m writing a chat application (client & server) using C in VS 2010.

I have finished writing my code as you can see below but there is still a problem.
This problem is that the client doesn't receive on time the messages that server sends.

Server code :

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>



main()
{

    SOCKET          ListeningSocket;
    SOCKET          AcceptSocket;

    SOCKADDR_IN     ServerAddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN     ClientAddr;

    WSADATA         wsaData;

    const unsigned short PORT = 4444;

    FD_SET          fdread;
    FD_SET          BackUpfdread;
    FD_SET          fdwrite;
    FD_SET          BackUpfdwrite;

    int             maxDescriptor;
    SOCKET          SocketArray[20];
    int             index = 0;
    int             selectResults;
    int             i,k;
    int             clientAddrSize;
    int             RecvBytes;
    int             SentBytes;

    char            SentBuff[500];
    char            RecvBuff[500];

    struct  timeval timeout;


    // Initialize Winsock2.2
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);

    // Initialize Listening Socket
    ListeningSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);


    // Initialize ServerAddr
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the ServerAddr with ListeningSocket
    bind(ListeningSocket,(SOCKADDR *)&ServerAddr,sizeof(ServerAddr));

    // Listening Socket
    listen(ListeningSocket,5);

    FD_ZERO(&fdread);
    FD_ZERO(&BackUpfdread);
    FD_ZERO(&fdwrite);
    FD_ZERO(&BackUpfdwrite);

    // Asign ListeningSocket at fdread
    FD_SET(ListeningSocket,&fdread);

    maxDescriptor = ListeningSocket;

    SocketArray[index] = ListeningSocket;
    index++;

    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    // Main loop starts here
    for(; ;)
    {

        BackUpfdread = fdread;
        BackUpfdwrite = fdwrite;
        selectResults = select(maxDescriptor+1,&BackUpfdread,&BackUpfdwrite,NULL,&timeout);
        //printf("server select() OK\n");

        if(selectResults == -1)
        {
            printf("Select() error");
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }


        for(i=0;i<=index-1;i++)
        {
            //printf("%d\n",SocketArray[i]);
            if(FD_ISSET(SocketArray[i],&BackUpfdread))
            {
                if(SocketArray[i] == ListeningSocket) // we have a new connection
                {
                    clientAddrSize = sizeof(ClientAddr);
                    AcceptSocket = accept(ListeningSocket,(SOCKADDR *)&ClientAddr,&clientAddrSize);

                    // Add the newest accepted socket to the fdread and fdwrite sets.
                    FD_SET(AcceptSocket,&fdread);
                    FD_SET(AcceptSocket,&fdwrite);

                    // Add the newest accepted socket into SocketArray
                    SocketArray[index] = AcceptSocket;
                    index++;

                    // keep track of the maxDescriptor.
                    if(AcceptSocket > maxDescriptor)
                    {
                        maxDescriptor = AcceptSocket;
                    }

                    printf("New connection from %s on socket %d\n", inet_ntoa(ClientAddr.sin_addr), AcceptSocket);

                }else{ // That means that the socket is not from a new conection and has something sent.

                    memset(RecvBuff,0,sizeof(RecvBuff));
                    RecvBytes = recv(SocketArray[i], RecvBuff, sizeof(RecvBuff)-1, 0);

                    if(RecvBytes > 0) // Some data received.
                    {

                        printf("Message Sent.\n");
                        printf("Message was: %s\n",RecvBuff);

                        for(k=0;k<=index-1;k++)
                        {

                            if(SocketArray[k] != ListeningSocket && SocketArray[k] != SocketArray[i])
                            {
                                memset(SentBuff,0,sizeof(SentBuff));
                                strcpy(SentBuff,RecvBuff);
                                SentBytes = send(SocketArray[k],SentBuff,sizeof(SentBuff),0);

                                if(SentBytes > 0)
                                {
                                    printf("Message Forwarded\n");
                                }else{
                                    printf("Message forward error\n");
                                }

                            }


                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        SleepEx(10, FALSE);

    }// Main loop ends here


}
```

Client code :

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>



main()
{

    SOCKET          ConnectSocket;
    SOCKET          SocketArray[20];

    SOCKADDR_IN     ServerAddr;

    WSADATA         wsaData;

    FD_SET          fdwrite;
    FD_SET          fdread;
    FD_SET          BackUpfdread;
    FD_SET          BackUpfdwrite;

    char            server_address[20] = "192.168.1.4";
    char            SentBuff[500];
    char            RecvBuff[500];

    const unsigned short PORT = 4444;

    int             maxDescriptor;
    int             index = 0;
    int             SelectResults;
    int             i;
    int             RecvBytes;
    int             SentBytes;

    BOOL            bOpt = TRUE;

    struct timeval  timeout;




    // Initialize Winsock 2.2
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);

    // Initialize ServerAddr
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_address);
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Create a new socket to make a client connection.
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    setsockopt(ConnectSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,(char*)&bOpt,sizeof(BOOL));

    // Clear the fd sets
    FD_ZERO(&fdread);
    FD_ZERO(&BackUpfdread);
    FD_ZERO(&fdwrite);
    FD_ZERO(&BackUpfdwrite);

    // Asign ConnectSocket into fdread and fdwrite.
    FD_SET(ConnectSocket,&fdread);
    FD_SET(ConnectSocket,&fdwrite);

    // Set timer
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    maxDescriptor = ConnectSocket;
    SocketArray[index] = ConnectSocket;
    index++;

    // Make a connection to the server with socket s.
    if(connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Couldn't connect to the server\n");
    }


    // Main loop starts here
    for(; ;)
    {
        BackUpfdread = fdread;
        BackUpfdwrite = fdwrite;

        memset(SentBuff, 0, sizeof(SentBuff));
        printf("Write: ");
        gets_s(SentBuff, sizeof(SentBuff)); 

        SelectResults = select(maxDescriptor+1,&BackUpfdread,&BackUpfdwrite,NULL,&timeout);

        for(i=0;i<=index-1;i++)
        {
            // Something to read from server.
            if(FD_ISSET(SocketArray[i],&BackUpfdread) && SocketArray[i] == ConnectSocket) 
            {
                RecvBytes = recv(SocketArray[i], RecvBuff, sizeof(RecvBuff), 0);

                if(RecvBytes > 0)
                {
                    printf("%s\n",RecvBuff);   
                    // Cleaning the Receive Buffer 
                    memset(RecvBuff,0,sizeof(RecvBuff));
                }

            }

            // Something to write.
            if(FD_ISSET(SocketArray[i],&BackUpfdwrite) && SocketArray[i] == ConnectSocket)
            {
                SentBytes = send(SocketArray[i], SentBuff,sizeof(SentBuff),0);
                // Cleaning the Sent Buffer 
                memset(SentBuff,0,sizeof(SentBuff));

            }


        }

        SleepEx(10, FALSE);

    } // Main menu ends here

}
```

In my opinion something seems not working good at clients side. I m telling this because if i use telnet application as client messages transferred correct.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: I compiled your sources as given above can not reproduce the issue. The client receives back form the server what the user entered at client's console prompt (and even a bit more ... ;-))

Comment: What OS did you use ? You say that works fine for you ? Thats strange. Here is an image from my desktop. [link](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/871/51848612.png) As you can see client 1 writes hi and client 2 has to write something else to get the "hi" from first client and get worse with "whats up" later ..

Comment: I did the tests under win32/vista.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: As you are using a hard coded ip-address:port tuple to access the server, are you sure it is the correct on?

---

Client 2 does not *"... have to write something ..."* to receive, but is blocked in `gets_s()` waiting for user input, and therefore cannot `select()` and therefore cannot `recv()`.

To solve this blocking issue you can go for two approaches.

*1 Mulit-threaded solution (more portable)*

Change the client design to handle the server connection (writing to it and reading form it) asynchronously, for example in a different thread then the main thread.

*2 Single-threaded solution (non-portable)*

*2.1 Windows*

You can use `ReadConsoleEvent()` to implement non-blocking read from the console.

For example this could be done like this:

```
/*
 * Does a non-blocking read of characters from the stdin into the
 * buffer referenced by 'pszBuffer' up to a maximum of 'sizeBuffer'.
 *
 * If bEcho is TRUE the characters read are echoed to the console window.
 *
 * Returns the characters read or a negative value on error.
 */
DWORD ReadConsoleNonBlocking(char * pszBuffer, size_t sizeBuffer, BOOL bEcho)
{
  DWORD dwRC = 0;
  static HANDLE stdinHandle = 0;

  stdinHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

  {
    if (!pszBuffer)
      return -1;

    if (!sizeBuffer)
      return -2;

    {
      INPUT_RECORD input = {0};
      DWORD NumberOfEventsRead = 0;

      if (!ReadConsoleInput(stdinHandle, &input, 1, &NumberOfEventsRead)) 
        return -3;

      if (NumberOfEventsRead && (KEY_EVENT == input.EventType) && input.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
      {
        DWORD dwCharactersRead = 0;

        while (input.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount > dwCharactersRead && dwCharactersRead < sizeBuffer)
        {
          pszBuffer[dwCharactersRead] = input.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;

          if ('\r' == pszBuffer[dwCharactersRead])
            pszBuffer[dwCharactersRead] = '\n';

          if (bEcho)
            printf("%c", pszBuffer[dwCharactersRead]); /* echo character read to console */

          ++ dwCharactersRead;
        }

        dwRC = dwCharactersRead;
      }
    }
  }

  return dwRC;
}
```

*2.2 UNIX*

You can use the result of `fileno(stdin)` to retrieve the file descriptor for standard input and add it to the set of file descriptors passed to `select()` to be notified if something was entered via the console.

Comment: Yes i use the correct ip and port. The connection established fine.

Comment: Yes , i understand the problem but even if i put the gets_s() after the for(i=0;i<=index-1;i++) loop or after select() the problem still exists. Also how can this code get worked in your machine ? Is this possible ?

Comment: @F.N: I have the same issue here (the client only reading from the server after having received input from the console). For a possible approach to solve this issue please see me edited answer.

Comment: Ok this solution sounds good. This is how i imagine the client now. (1) `gets_s()` fills a buffer with user's input (2) send the buffer into the new thread (3) in the new thread there will be the `select()` doing its job. Now there were born some new questions. 1. Is it possible to pass a buffer to a thread ? 2. If the `CreateThread()` will be in for(; ; ) loop in of the main thread then each time a new thread will be created. 3.Maybe i have to pass not only the buffer but the fdsets (BackUpfdread & BackUpfdwrite) into the tread and i don't think that somethink like this could be happen.

Comment: @F.N: 1. See the fourth parameter of `CreateThread()` for passing initial data to a thread. 2. Yes, so place the call to `CreateThread()` somewhere more suitable. 3. You can do the whole connection setup in the thread. PS: Also I edited my post to mention a single-threaded approach to solve the issue of the blocked client.

Comment: I prefer multithread version but where i have to put the `CreateThread()` function confuse me little. Lets say to put it after the `connect()` out of the `for( ; ; )` loop and in the `for( ; ; )` loop , have only the `gets_s()` . How then i could send the buffer that `gets_s()` filled in the child thread ? Is there any way to do this ? Or im thinking too wrong ? Sorry but i don't know a lot about threads.

Comment: @F.N: `CreateThread()` could be called from `main()` before doing any read from the console. It creates the thread handling the server connection. The whole ip-stuff goes into this thread. The only more thing remaining in (the) main(-thread) is a (new) loop around `gets_s()` readng input from the console and then passing it to the thread created before.

Comment: Ok thanks i understand this. But how can you pass the console input without use of CreateThread function to the child thread? Is there any other function doing this (passing data to an already created thread) ?

Comment: @F.N: Threads share the same process memory, so the easiest was is to use a global variable. A more elegent way would be to use a variable referenced by the pointer passed to `CreateThread()`. Those two method require access synchonisation using a mutex or lock. Another third method would be use IPC to send the console data to the thread (please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1911203/694576) - anyhow such an approach seems somehow overdesigned to me, as it's not about passing data from process to proces here.

Comment: Yes , but isn't it mandatory to use such an approach while as you said before the `CreateThread()` will be called before read data from input ? How these data will be passed into the new thread ? How exactly are you thinking it (can you give a pseudo-code)? Maybe i m the one how is thinking false.

Comment: @F.N: Please see the fourth parameter of CreateThread() for passing initial data to a thread. A [...] way would be to use a variable referenced by the pointer passed to CreateThread().